# Securing API with SSL - what about database access?

Tags: security, ssl, encryption

OK, so everybody is securing their API with SSL. Cool, so people don't eavesdrop on messages and intercept passwords.

But what about the communication channel to the database? Typically you'll have your app server serving the API through SSL, but it's going to write data to the database.

We'll have the database behind a separate firewall.
Still this wouldn't prevent an attacker from trying to listen on the communication channel to the database and getting information from there.

But I never heard that the communication channel to the database be encrypted.

Is that an overlooked issue or am I too paranoid here?

Comment: 1) The connections you speak of are often not encrypted by default, but can usually be configured to be, or tunneled to be. 2) This is probably more of a question for [Security.se]

Comment: not sure about policies, but I am tempted to crosspost there then...

Comment: You can just delete this and check out there. But I would definitely search. I'm almost positive you won't have to ask this question - copious answers should be there already. There, and [dba.se]

Comment: Indeed. Here are relevant questions: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14334/when-is-it-appropriate-to-ssl-encrypt-database-connections
http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32482/should-i-use-ssl-on-my-database-server

Comment: Excellent! And kudos for caring about this sort of thing, too!

Comment: thank *you* for providing the hints